# SQL Server - Criar Visão num servidor com tabelas de outro servidor

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Olá.

Tínhamos um servidor SQL Server com três bancos, um da aplicação que eu desenvolvo, outros dois de dois sistemas distintos, sistema ERP da Empresa e sistema de Pedidos OnLine.

Esse sistema de Pedidos OnLine roda 24hs, então está sempre atualizando o banco, inserindo itens novos, comparando descrições e consultando o saldo de estoque dos produtos no Sistema ERP. Isso tem pesado muito no desempenho onde é executado outro sistema para baixar as informações de um para o outro.

No meu sistema, preciso cruzar as informações dos dois bancos mais o meu, por exemplo, saber se um cliente está cadastrado, quem é o vendedor ou se um pedido já foi importado. Há dias dias tranquilos mas outros dá erro de timeout numa consulta ou outra.

Resolvemos por o banco do Sistema OnLine em outro servidor e resolveu o problema de desempenho. Mas criamos outro. Como fazer uma consulta cruzando bancos e tabelas de dois servidores?

Estou pesquisando, mas ainda não cheguei numa conclusão. Estou querendo criar visões das tabelas que preciso no meu servidor com das tabelas do banco OnLine, não sei se é possível fazer isso. Será que alguém já teve esse problema de cruzar informações em dois servidores?

O sistema que estou desenvolvendo é em VB.Net.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido, porem não foi de performance. Tínhamos  4 bases, uma local e 3 em locais remotos. Nós criamos uma replicação do tipo snapshot dos bancos remotos. Assim periodicamente o servidor local "recebia" o snapshot dos bancos remotos. Os snapshots eram somente para consulta e o local era usado normalmente.

Comment: Já considerou o uso de Linked Server?

Comment: @cantoni Sim, estava pesquisando em como fazer esse Linked Server. Isso ainda é novidade pra mim, mas parecer ser uma boa alternativa.

Comment: @LindomarLemos, essa é uma boa opção se os servidores estiverem dentro da mesma rede.

Comment: Acho que você procura algo semelhante a [isto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143199/tsql-create-a-view-that-accesses-multiple-databases).

Comment: Sim. vi lá a sintaxe:  {LINKED_SERVER.}DATABASE.SCHEMA.OBJECT. Será que onde está LINKED_SERVER devo por o IP do servidor? Depois: BD2.dbo.Clientes. Completo seria: {192.168.1.1\filial}.DB2.dbo.Clientes. Será que é algo assim?